# How to add a field in embedded document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that looks like this:

```
 {
    first_name:"A",
    last_name:"B",
    subjects:
      {
        literature:"Eng",
        science:"Physics",
        //How can i add field here e.g., socialStudies:"History"
      }
  }
```

Here, the field `subjects` is not an array. It's a sub-document in which I want to add a new field. For example, how can I add `socialStudies: "History"` inside the subdocument?

Comment: Use dot notation

Comment: You have to provide sample code which you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call *$set* using dot notation.

```
db.collection_name.update({first_name :'A'}, {$set : { "subjects.socialStudies" : "History" }})
```

Comment: I tried to do this but then subjects will contain only socialStudies, previously added fields will lost.

Comment: No it will not be lost. It will set a new field keeping the existing keys literature and science

Comment: Thanks.. :) Earlier when i tried this query, there was a typo error. Missed {} for $set.